# How do I extract information from a text file after a certain word in python or linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I'm writing a regression script in python to verify that our library passes all unit tests. I am writing all of the output to a `.txt` file that needs to be named in this format: `reg_results_yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss_rrrrrr_ssssss.txt`, where `yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss` is the year, month, day of the month, hour, minute, and second, `rrrrrr` is the revision number of our library and `ssssss` is either PASSED or FAILED.

In the log file, it will state "Checked out revision 129", where 129 will be the number that is changing. I need to extract whatever number is after "revision". At the end of the log file, it will state "PASSED Unit Tests" or "FAILED Unit Tests", and I need to extract the PASSED/FAILED.

I'm wondering how to search the log file and extract the revision number and PASSED/FAILED from it, in order to appropriately rename the log file.

I've looked into the **grep** linux command, but am unsure how to only grab specific pieces of the information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex either with grep (from Bash) or, since you tagged this Python:

```
import re

with open('/tmp/tgt.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        m=re.match(r'Checked out revision (\d+)\s+(\w+)', line)
        if m:
            print m.group(1), m.group(2)
```

Given a file like so:

```
blah
blew blah
blah de blah
Checked out revision 129 PASSED Unit Test
blah
blew blah
Checked out revision 135 FAILED Unit Test
blah de blah
```

Prints:

```
129 PASSED
135 FAILED
```

Comment: Does (\d+) match the digits, \s+ matches the spaces and (\w+) matches the word? Then, when printing out the group, (1) correlates to (\d+) and (2) correlates to (\w+)? Just trying to understand the code. This is exactly what I'm looking for, though. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have interpreted both the regex and the groups correctly. You can use a similar regex with Grep or Sed if you just want a cl tool to do it, or write a little Perl or Python. Beware that in Python `re.match` only matches at the start of the string; use `re.search` to search throughout the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
import re

rev = None
pass_or_fail = None

with open(path_to_your_log_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if rev is None:
            found_rev = re.findall(r'Checked out revision (\d+)', line):
            if found_rev:
                rev = int(found_rev[0])
                continue
        if pass_or_fail is None:
            found_pass_fail = re.findall(r'(PASSED|FAILED) Unit Tests', line):
            if found_pass_fail:
                pass_or_fail = found_pass_fail[0]
        if pass_or_fail is not None and rev is not None:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `sed`. If everything is on one line (as suggested in another answer), it's very easy:

```
sed -n 's/^Checked out revision \([0-9]\+\) \(FAILED\|PASSED\) Unit Tests$/\1 \2/p'
```

If the two bits you're interested in are on different lines, it's a wee bit harder, but easy enough if you recognise a `sed` idiom or two:

```
sed -n '/^Checked out revision \([0-9]\+\)/{s//\1/;h}; /^\(FAILED\|PASSED\) Unit Tests$/{s//\1/;H;g;s/\n/ /p}'
```

This bears a little explanation:

```
sed -n '/^Checked out revision \([0-9]\+\)$/{    # Match revision, capture number
    s//\1/    # Make matched group (number) the only thing in pattern space
    h         # Save the pattern space (number) to hold space
}
/^\(FAILED\|PASSED\) Unit Tests$/{    # Match pass/fail line, capturing pass/fail
    s//\1/    # Make pass/fail the only thing in pattern space
    H         # Append pattern space to hold space with newline
    g         # Fetch hold space to pattern space
    s/\n/ /   # Replace newline with space
    p         # Print out pattern space
}'
```